# AttributeError at /notify/notify/ 'UserNotifications' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a notifications app. I have a middle that collects info about the action the user should be notified about and in the view that handles the action it automatically creates an instance in the `UserNotification` model. This is all working. Now, if a user's post gets liked by another user, that actions needs to be displayed on the notifications page. However, I obviously don't want any one use to be able to see every notification that is being created on the site, but rather only the notifications that are created by their posts.

I am running into an issue with the view and filtering the notifications based on the current user. More specifically, I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError at /notify/notify/
'UserNotifications' object has no attribute 'user'
```

With traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 160, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "/Users/garrettlove/Desktop/evverest/notify/views.py", line 30, in get_queryset
    return UserNotification.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Here is my view pertaining to this:

```
// Bunch of imports are all here

User = get_user_model()

class UserNotifications(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = 'account_login'
    model = UserNotification
    template_name = 'notify/usernotification_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'notifies'
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(request):
        return UserNotification.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Here is my `UserNotification` model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class UserNotification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('feed.UserPost',related_name='post')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notify_type = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return UserNotification.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```